# Ionic: reload view after updating $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Here's my controller:

```
// Product already in wishlist. Remove it.
console.log('Erase product');

var wishlistLink = "mylink";

$http.post(wishlistLink, {
  user_id: $window.sessionStorage.id,
  product_id: product
}).then(function(res) {
  localWLArray = JSON.parse($window.sessionStorage.lz_r);
  localWLArray.pop(product);
  $window.sessionStorage.lz_r = JSON.stringify(localWLArray);
  if(!$scope.$$phase) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
      delete $scope.products[key].ulz;
    });
  }
  $state.go($state.$current, null, { reload: true });
});
```

Now, my scope variable updates just fine. I just can't get to reload the template, which contains `ng-class="{ 'ulz': product.ulz === '' }"` to make sure that element gets new class. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed it by removing apply function, and left what was inside it, outside. Works like a charm.